# The bundle currently has rails locked at 3.2.12. whats to do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundle

I've changed in my gemfile the rails version from 3.2.12 to 4.2.0

then I got this error:

```
The bundle currently has rails locked at 3.2.12
```

so I tried bundle update / and bundle update rails ... but I got this:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
prototype-rails (>= 0) ruby depends on
  rails (~> 3.2) ruby

rails (4.2.0)
```

What do I have to do?

Update Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
#gem 'rails', '3.2.12'
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
gem "airbrake"
#gem "mysql"
gem 'mysql2',  '~>0.3.7'
gem 'fastercsv'
gem 'newrelic_rpm', :group => [:production, :staging]
gem "xml-simple", :require => "xmlsimple"
gem "will_paginate", "~> 3.0.0"
gem "json", '1.7.7'
gem "default_value_for"
gem "whenever"
gem 'charlock_holmes'
gem 'prototype-rails'
gem 'rails_autolink'

group :development do
  gem 'capistrano'
  gem 'capistrano-ext'
end
```

Comment: Show your `Gemfile`.

Comment: I've updated it above

Comment: remove your gemfile.lock `rm Gemfile.lock`

Comment: remove your gemfile.lock `rm Gemfile.lock`, then add `rails 4.2.0` in your `Gemfile` then `bundle install`

Comment: thanks i've done this .. works ... but now the webrick dosn't start the app ...

/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n.rb:284:in `enforce_available_locales!': :de is not a valid locale (I18n::InvalidLocale)
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n/config.rb:34:in `default_locale='
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n.rb:35:in `default_locale='

Comment: IN your `application.rb` file add `i18n.config.enforce_available_locales = false`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just run

```
bundle update
```

without telling to update just a specific gem (like rails). This allows `bundler` to find the lastest possible combination for all gems in the `Gemfile`.

The [prototype-rails gem](https://github.com/rails/prototype-rails#support-for-rails-41-and-above) is not actively supported anymore. You should try to replace it as soon as possible (even if the latest version still works for you).

Furthermore: Multiple configuration settings have changed between [Rails 3.2 and 4.2](http://railsdiff.org/3.2.12/4.2.0), you will have to change some of your config and core files. You also might want to read the [Rails Guide: Upgrading Rails](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html).

I suggest to upgrade your app in smaller steps (3.2 -> 4.0, 4.0 -> 4.1, 4.1 -> 4.2). Make sure that the app works in each step before you continue to the next. Also, watch out for deprecation warnings in the console or the logs.

Comment: thanks for hint. webrick tells me lots of lots of errors. Is there a documentation or something like that how I can upgrade from 3.2 to 4.2

Comment: @Felix: I updated my answer with a link to the upgrade guidelines.

Comment: Thanks. Do I have to do all steps. First von 3.2 to 4.0
and then from 4.0 to 4.1 and then from 4.1 to 4.2 ?

Comment: @Felix: It helps a lot to do all steps one after the other. Each version has small changes or deprecations. It is easier to find and fix problems as if you try to to it in one big step.

Comment: In case of this: `Rails 4.0 no longer supports loading plugins from vendor/plugins. You must replace any plugins by extracting them to gems and adding them to your Gemfile. If you choose not to make them gems, you can move them into, say, lib/my_plugin/* and add an appropriate initializer in config/initializers/my_plugin.rb.` which is the esier way? ....

Comment: It is probably easier to just move the plugin into the lib folder then to extract them to gems. You might want to check first if there are new gem versions of your older plugins available (find gems by name: https://rubygems.org/).

Comment: When I move them to lib folder. Whats to do then?. ... `add an appropriate initializer in config/initializers/my_plugin.rb.` how should looks like such an initializer?

Comment: Please start a new question about how to do that, because is does not really fit to the original question anymore. And you might attract others to help with a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think, the problem is in prototype-rails

https://github.com/rails/prototype-rails

Below Comment of prototype-rails gem
*Unfortunately, due to limited manpower and resources, the Rails core team has not been able to confirm if this gem currently works with Rails 4.1 and above. If you have found any problems while upgrading your application, please report them at the issue tracker, or better yet, submit patches by sending a pull request.*

Tried to remove first remove prototype-rails then run

```
bundle update
```

Answer (score 1):

remove your `gemfile.lock`

```
rm Gemfile.lock
```

then add 
`rails 4.2.0` in your Gemfile
 then

```
bundle install
```

Comment: error is in config/application.rb lin 79

`I18n.default_locale = Settings.default_locale.to_sym`

Comment: Add this line to `application.rb` file `i18n.config.enforce_available_locales = false`

Comment: instead of mine or additionally`?

Comment: You will have `i18n.config.enforce_available_locales = true` just set that to `false`

Comment: No i don't have this line should I add it?

Comment: try, or you can add `config.i18n.default_locale = :en`

Comment: okay now it uses rails 4.2 and server dosn't start lots of errors

Comment: do `bundle update` as already suggested by @spickermann, It will update all rails dependency gems

Comment: You can follow this tutorial http://technology.customink.com/blog/2014/09/16/from-rails-3.2-to-4.2/